# Apollo readFragment of optimistic response

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

### What I try to do

- I have an app which should work offline.
- There is an **Item-list**. I can add an **Item** to this list with a mutation.
- The update function of the mutation adds the **Item** to the **Item-list**. (Optimistic Response)
- When I click on an **Item**, I want to see the **details**.

### My Implementation

Content of Mutation update function:

```
  const queryData = cache.readQuery<{ items: Item[] }>({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: {
      filter
    }
  });
  if (!queryData?.items) {
    return;
  }
  const newData = [...queryData.items, newItem];
  cache.writeQuery({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    data: { items: newData },
    variables: {
      filter
    }
  });
```

Get details of the item in the vue-file:

```
apolloProvider.clients.defaultClient
      .readFragment<Item>({
        fragment: ITEM_FRAGMENT,
        id:id
      });
```

### The problem

Adding the item to the Query-result works fine.
When I try to read the fragment:

1. I get **null** for items which were added by the Mutation update function
2. I get the expected object for items which were fetched from the backend
   There is also the optimistic attribute in readFragment, but that doesn't make a difference.

### Other observations

When I write and immediately read the fragment in the Mutation update function, I am able to get it.

```
  cache.writeFragment({
    fragment: ITEM_FRAGMENT,
    data: item,
    id: item._id,
  });
  const data = cache.readFragment({
    fragment: ITEM_FRAGMENT,
    id: item._id,
  });
  console.log({ data }); // This logs my item Object
```

### Package versions:

```
{
"@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.1-rc.3",
"apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
"nuxt": "^2.0.0",
}
```

### Summary

apollo.readFragement doesn't work for values from an optimistic response.

Maybe someone here has an idea of what I am missing, or a different approach to implement this functionality

Comment: were you ever able to find any other info on this?

Comment: No unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 3):

To get optimistic values from apollo cache you need to add `true` as second parameter in your `readFragment` call.

```
readFragment(options, optimistic)
```

(`optimistic` is `false` by default.)

In your case:

```
apolloProvider.clients.defaultClient
  .readFragment<Item>({
    fragment: ITEM_FRAGMENT,
    id:id
  }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look next year and update this question if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an optimistic response for a resource that is in the process of being created via a mutation (e.g. your `item`), we need to assign some kind of temporary id to the optimistic data ([see example in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/#example-adding-a-new-object-to-a-list)). This is because the real resource hasn’t been created yet and we don’t know it’s id.

Given this, to read the optimistic response from the cache we need to use that same temporary id (as well as the `__typename`). When the mutation completes and we have the real response in the cache the optimistic response is discarded and we can use the real id.

I ran into this recently as I was assigning a temporary id, but not using it to retrieve the optimistic response from the cache to render the updated UI in that brief window where I was waiting for the mutation to complete.